# Using Vertex Buffer Objects with gluPerspective

Tags: java, opengl

I'm trying to learn about Vertex Buffer Objects. I've been able to successfully render a quad in 2D space (using `glOrtho` during initialization), but I'm having trouble using VBOs when rendering using `gluPerspective`.

I'm using Java and the LWJGL and have attached my code below. Currently, nothing but the black clear renders to the window.

```
public class GameWindow {
    // Height and width of the viewport
    private final int WIDTH = 800;
    private final int HEIGHT = 600;

    private final float zNear = 1f;
    private final float zFar = 1000f;

    long lastFrame, lastFps;
    int fps;

    public void start() {
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluPerspective(90, WIDTH / HEIGHT, zNear, zFar);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();

        float[] quadCoords = {
                100, 100, -1,
                300, 100, -1,
                300, 300, -1,
                100, 300, -1
        };

        float[] colorCoords = {
                1, 0, 0,
                0, 1, 0,
                0, 0, 1,
                1, 0, 1
        };

        FloatBuffer vertexData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(4 * 3);
        vertexData.put(quadCoords);
        vertexData.flip();

        FloatBuffer colorData = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(4 * 3);
        colorData.put(colorCoords);
        colorData.flip();

        int vboVertex = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVertex);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        int vboColor = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboColor);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        getDelta();
        lastFps = TimeUtil.getTime();

        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            int delta = getDelta();
            updateFPS();
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboVertex);
            glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboColor);
            glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);

            glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
            glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
            glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
            glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

            Display.update();
            Display.sync(60);
        }
        Display.destroy();
    }

    private int getDelta() {
        long time = TimeUtil.getTime();
        int delta = (int) (time - lastFrame);
        lastFrame = time;

        return delta;
    }

    public void updateFPS() {
        if (TimeUtil.getTime() - lastFps > 1000) {
            Display.setTitle("FPS: " + fps);
            fps = 0;
            lastFps += 1000;
        }
        fps++;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GameWindow window = new GameWindow();
        window.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your quad's vertices are out of view. Without setting up a view matrix (by means of gluLookAt, for example), the camera points to the -Z axis. You asked zNear and zFar to be 1.0 and 1000.0, so everything between the z-coordinate -1.0 and -1000.0 will be drawn (zNear and zFar are something like the "distance" to the camera). You also have to take into account that perspective projection is really different from orthographic. I'd say, try moving your vertices back on the Z axis, like so:

```
float[] quadCoords = {
        100, 100, -500,
        300, 100, -500,
        300, 300, -500,
        100, 300, -500
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your near clipping plane is 1 but your rendering all the z coordinates at -1